# Sequential criterion of limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. A genric variable for $\mathbb{R}$ is $x$ and a generic variable for $\mathbb{N}$ is $n$.

We know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$ implies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = L$. I sense that the converse is not true, but I am not able to find/construct an appropriate counter example. Do you have any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, Prof. Santos.